# How to make all the elements of a RecyclerView, EXCEPT the first element, overlay the rest of the content of Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout, android-overlay

I have an Activity with a `RecyclerView` and then a `FrameLayout` below it. Initially, the RecyclerView has one element which is a `LinearLayout`, and the rest of the elements will be added at runtime (those will also be LinearLayouts). The first picture below shows this initial setup.

Then at runtime (see the second picture below), some more `LinearLayout`s will be added to the `RecyclerView`(collectively shown as the green box).

**Now the CHALLENGE is that** the blue `FrameLayout` does not get overlapped or overlayed by the *`LinearLayout` with orange border*. But when the *green `LinearLayout`* is added to the `RecyclerView`, it should overlay everything (essentially the blue FrameLayout) under it.

**One way would be** to actually make the entire RecyclerView overlay everything else, and give the FrameLayout a `paddingTop` value equal to the height of the *orange `LinearLayout`*? But the **problem with that** is that (1)it seems hacky so it should probably be done when there is no other way (2) I don't know what the height of the orange LinearLayout (since it is `wrap_content`).

**So how should I go about it?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping I got things right, I would go with your proposed solution. It does not seem that hacky to me actually.
You can always measure the first `LinearLayout` once it gets laid out and set the padding accordingly.

```
  getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() { 
               getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
               measureAndSetPadding();
            }
  });
```